# Qual é a diferença entre findByIdAndRemove e findByIdAndDelete no Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Estou procurando a diferença entre os dois e não consigo achar. São sinônimos?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi...[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602037/difference-between-findoneanddelete-and-findoneandremove)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR - Os dois fazem a mesma coisa de maneiras diferentes, mas recomenda-se usar o `findByIdAndDelete()`.

A pequena diferença é que o `findByIdAndDelete()` usa a função nativa do MongoDB `findOneAndDelete()` para remover e a `findByIdAndRemove()` usa a função nativa do MongoDB `findAndModify()` para fazer a mesma coisa. Esta função (`findAndModify()`) foi descontinuada (*deprecated*) e a documentação do Mongoose recomenda utilizar a `findByIdAndDelete()`.

> This function differs slightly from `Model.findOneAndRemove()` in that
>   `findOneAndRemove()` becomes a MongoDB `findAndModify()` command, as
>   opposed to a `findOneAndDelete()` command. For most mongoose use
>   cases, this distinction is purely pedantic. You should use
>   `findOneAndDelete()` unless you have a good reason not to.

Referências:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602037/difference-between-findoneanddelete-and-findoneandremove
2. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete
3. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete
4. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#findAndModify

Comment: TL;DR = "too long; didn't read." -> Usado para dar um resumo de um post que é muito grande. Não é o caso!

Comment: Quatro frases é mais longo que uma frase. Sim, é o caso.